# Substituting something with empty string?

Tags: regular-expression, substitute

How can I substitute something with empty string? So far the best I can do seems to be substituting with a whitespace. If I write `:s/target//` then it's deemed invalid.

Comment: The command work well for me. What error message do you get?

Comment: @statox Actually it worked this time. I'm not sure what happened previously. The solution posted by Tumbler41 also worked.

Comment: BTW, `:s/target` is even shorter :)

Comment: @VanLaser Cool. But that doesn't work in cases where I want to append flags, apparently.

Comment: Downvotes without explanation? Guess this question shouldn't have existed in the first place anyways then. Since it can't be deleted by myself already, I'm flagging for the mods to deal with it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your command should work but you could also try this as an alternative:

```
:s/target/\=''/
```

- `\=` tells vim to evaluate the replace string as an expression
- `''` Is an empty string

Comment: Actually it worked this time. Your solution also worked.

Comment: @tumbler41 from [`:h :s%`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#:s%): `When {string} is equal to "%" and '/' is included with the 'cpoptions' option, then the {string} of the previous substitute command is used.` (`{string}` is defined as `:[range]s[ubstitute]/{pattern}/{string}/[flags]` in [`:h :substitute`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#:substitute)) . And empty replacement string should work :-)

Comment: Ok, I was thinking of if you omit the first pattern string, then it uses the last pattern for **that**. I'll remove that from my answer.